# In python can datetime.datetime values be plotted using Matplotlib? ?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

```
In [22]: x
Out[22]: 
[datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 14, 1, 37, 6),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 14, 1, 40, 32),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 14, 1, 52, 57),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 14, 1, 55, 26)]

In [23]: y
Out[23]: [-209.0, -614.0, -43.0, -438.0]

In [31]: plot(x,y)
Out[31]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x35e4e10>]

In [32]: show() 

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

I want to plot x Vs. y and whenever I call the show() function I get an error. Does somebody have experience with this? And can you provide a solution/suggestion ?

Comment: What version of MPL are you using? When I run your code I get no errors.

Comment: Can you also post the stack trace that goes with that error?  and do you have `pandas` imported?

Comment: The origin of you exception is completely unclear. You can use `traceback.print_exc()` to get all necessary information.

Comment: @bernie: My MPL version is 1.10

Comment: Well, it seems to be working and plotting the way I want it to now. Thanks anyways guys.

Comment: @kb16 If you have solved your own problem you should also answer your own question.